# VB.Net MySqlConnection DataAdapter returns zero rows for Selects after MySqlCommandBuilder GetUpdateCommand()

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

Visual Basic 2010 Express 
MySQL Connector/Net 5.2.7 
MySQL Server 5.5.16 
Windows 7 Professional 64Bit 
Also tried on Windows XP 32 Bit with MySQL Connector/Net 5.0.x

MySqlDataAdapter returns zero rows on Select statements after calling MySqlCommandBuilder GetUpdateCommand() method. No errors are thrown, and the Update is successful. Select statements return rows if I comment-out the GetUpdateCommand() and Update() lines. If I just comment out the Update() line, the problem remains, so the problem has to do with GetUpdateCommand() and not the Update() itself.

There are two tables in the database I am connecting to, each with the same schema and content:

test_table  & different_table 
id INT Primary Key 
name VARCHAR(45)

Each have five rows: 
1 - name 
2 - name 
...etc

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Open Connection to test database'
    Dim mscConnection As MySqlConnection
    mscConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    mscConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=testdb"
    mscConnection.Open()

    'Get records from test table'
    Dim msdaDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsDataSet As New DataSet
    msdaDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM test_table", mscConnection)
    msdaDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet, "test_table")

    'Show record count (result is 5)'
    Console.WriteLine(dsDataSet.Tables("test_table").Rows.Count)

    'Loop through rows and change the name field of each one'
    For Each row As DataRow In dsDataSet.Tables("test_table").Rows
        row("name") = "new name"
    Next

    'Update altered rows'
    Dim mscbCommandBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder()
    mscbCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(msdaDataAdapter)
    mscbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    msdaDataAdapter.Update(dsDataSet, "test_table")

    'Have tried with and without RefreshSchema/Dispose/Nothing'
    mscbCommandBuilder.RefreshSchema()
    mscbCommandBuilder.Dispose()
    mscbCommandBuilder = Nothing

    'Try to Select again'
    'Get records from test table'
    msdaDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM test_table", mscConnection)
    msdaDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet, "test_table_2")

    'Show record count: result is 0 :/'
    Console.WriteLine(dsDataSet.Tables("test_table_2").Rows.Count)

    'Try a different table'
    msdaDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM different_test_table", mscConnection)
    msdaDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet, "different_test_table")

    'Show record count: result is 0'
    Console.WriteLine(dsDataSet.Tables("different_test_table").Rows.Count)
    mscConnection.Close()
    mscConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

If I re-click the button attached to the code a second time (without closing/re-opening the app), **ALL** Select statements return zero rows.

The connection isn't being closed after the Update(). If I try to (re)open the connection after the update, I get an error saying the connection is already open.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? How do I update so that I can continue to select further down the code?